# Error: use of unresolved identifier for NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,

Tags: ios, swift

I have a line of code:

```
var path: NSArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, true)
```

Xcode throws a compile time error:

```
use of unresolved identifier : NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask
```

I cannot figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
var path: NSArray= NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let documentsUrl = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first as NSURL
if let documentsPath = documentsUrl.path {
    println(documentsPath)
}
```

Comment: if you need the path you can use documentsUrl.path!

Comment: Thanks! Your answer just works as well. I got the code from objective-c but it seems NSDocumentDirectory is no longer there anymore...

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSSearchPathDirectory

Comment: BTW if you type NSSearchPathDirectory. and press escape it shows you all options available

Answer (score 1):

```
let paths = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
let documentsURL = paths[0] as NSURL
```